# Não consigo arrastar TextView para Layout no Android Studio

Tags: android, textview

Boa tarde.
Estou começando no Android Studio.
Já na instalação do Android Studio, já deu problema.
Quando estava instalando, meu wifi desligou, e parou a instalação.
Aí resolvi desinstalar e instalar de novo.
Instalei, só que a instalação foi bem mais rápida.
Para começar a aprender, na internet , achei como fazer seu primeiro app.
Abri o Android Studio, estou com as telas activity_main.xml , AndroidManifest.xml e MainActivity.java abertas.
O problema se arrasto qualquer componente da Palette para Surface, como exemplo uma TextView, ela não fixa na Surface.
Observei que tenho um erro : The rendering library could not be initialized .

O que já fiz :
Em Tools->SDK Manager->System Settings->Android SDK->instalei Android 4.3(Jelly Bean) , observação, o Android 10.0+(R) já estava instalado.

Em Tools->AVD Manager->Create Virtual Device-> instalei.

Mas ainda não consigo arrastar nenhum componente.

Obrigado.

Answer (score 0):

Boa tarde.
Achei o que estava dando errado.
No site , procurei o erro que estava dando:
***The rendering library could not be initialized***
e um usuário **NULL**, passou a resposta:
Em File->Settings->Experimental->Editor-> desmarcar ***Use New Layout Rendering Engine*** .
Funcionando.